# Как правильно сделать 2 update в mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

требуется обработать выборку данных, а потом сделать действия над одной из записей в выборке

как правильно это сделать?

через `promise`, `callback` или `setTimeout`

```
model.update( { groupId : groupId }, { field1 : val1, field2 : val2 } )
```

`UPDATE`

пробовал несколько вариантов, но либо второй `update` срабатывает раньше времени

c `promise'

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
model.update({
    groupId: 5,
    order: {$gte: 0, $lt: 3}
},
{ $inc: { order: 1 } },
{ multi: true })
.then(function(){
    model.update({
        id: 7
    },{
        order: 0
    });
});
```

или с `callback'

```
model.update({
    groupId: 5,
    order: {$gte: 0, $lt: 3}
},
{ $inc: { order: 1 } },
{ multi: true },
function(er, o){
    err && console.error(err);
    model.update({
        id: 7
    },{
        order: 0
    });
});
```

, либо изменений вообще не проиcходит

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
model.find({
    groupId: 5,
    order: {$gte: 0, $lt: 3}
})
.exec()
.then(function(ar){
    for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        ar[i].order++;
    }
    return ar;
})
.then(function(){
    model.update({
        id: 7
    },{
        order: 0
    });
});
```

подскажите, что сделано не правильно?

Comment: в последнем случае нужно `return ar.save();` скорее всего

Comment: @vp_arth, в варианте с `promise` мы не можем использовать `update` вместо `find` ? или здесь тоже ограничение изза `thenables` ?

Comment: Единственная разница с find - чтобы получить Promise нужно вызвать exec у thennables. При замене find на update, этот exec необходимо убрать.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` всегда **нет**, он никак не связан с запросом в БД, поэтому у вас никогда нет никаких гарантий, что вы дождётесь окончания запроса.

А вот `promises` или `callbacks` - дело вкуса.

Вложенные функции обратного вызова часто превращаются в ад.

Обещания более современны и позволяют сделать код более читаемым.
Важно помнить, что запросы(`find`) в `Mongoose` возвращают, там т.н. `thenables`, а не `promise`.  Чтобы получить `promise` необходимо вызвать метод `.exec()` у результата.
Также, в [документации](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) показывается, насколько легко подключить нативные `Promise` вместо встроенных `mpromise`:

```
// Use native promises
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Но и те, и другие позволят вам выполнить вашу задачу.

---

Пример:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
Users.find({group_id: 5}).exec()
  .then(users => {
    // обработка пользователей
    return users[0];    
  })
  .then(user => Users.update({id: user.id}, {$inc: {counter: 1}}))
  .then(() => console.log('finished'))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

---

К обновлению вопроса:

```
var p = model.find({
    groupId: 5,
    order: {$gte: 0, $lt: 3}
}).exec();

p.then(function(ar){
    for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        ar[i].order++;
        ar[i].save();
    }
    return ar;
}).then(function(){
    return model.update(
      {id: 7}, 
      {$set: {order: 0}}
    );
}).then(function(){
  console.log('finished');
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log('error: ', err);
});;
```

Comment: теорию я понимаю, а ссылкой на рабочий пример не поделитесь?

Comment: к сожалению так и не удалось последовательно выполнить 2 `update` , обновил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```js
model.update(
  {
    groupId: 5,
    order: {
      $gte: 0,
      $lt: 3
    }
  }, 
  {
    $inc: {
      order: 1
    }
  },
  { multi: true },
  function(err, o) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      model.update({id: 7}, {order: 0}, function(err, res) {
        console.log('done');
      });
    }
  }
 );
```